# Low poly render shows grey polygons

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, properties, custom-properties

I'm new to 3D, when I try to render my first model it shows some grey polygons throughout the body of the character. Face Orientation is all correct. I'm using Cycles... Eevee makes the render a little better, but still shows some polys greyed-out.

For context: Before I started making this project(it has only 508 Tris), I changed the render settings according to Ponte Ryuurui's Hard Surface tutorial. Also this was my first time actually pressing the button to render something.

[image]

[image: face orientation is correct]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably duplicate geometry which has visibility disabled in viewport, but not in render? In the *Outliner* window to the right, above the "Char.001" collection I see a collection named "Char" (duplicate of the other?) with the eye symbol disabled (visibility in viewport) but the camera symbol still enabled (visibility in render).

[image: disabled viewport, enabled render]

Comment: Thank you so much, that was such a small detail. The interface is still overwhelming to me as a beginner I completely forgot about that. You're a life saver man, thank you!!!!